# AutoHotkey syntax highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: syntax, notepad++, autohotkey

I would like to display syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey `.ahk` script files in Notepad++.

I don't want to manually select a language every time I open an AHK script. I want language-specific syntax to be applied automatically when the file is opened.

Comment: Could [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106178/7644018) possibly help?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[Thanks to jNizM for their helpful guide on the AHK forums.](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=50)

> ## Setup Notepad++ for AutoHotkey
>
> #### Syntax-Highlighting
>
> 1. Download [`userDefineLang_AHK.xml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus/master/userDefineLang/default/userDefineLang_AHK.xml) as raw (Right-click and choosing save as target...)
> 2. Start Notepad++ and click on Menu `Language -> Define your language`
> 3. Click `Import...` and select the file you downloaded in step 1
> 4. Restart Notepad++
>
>    - **[Default Theme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus/master/userDefineLang/default/userDefineLang_AHK.xml)** ([Preview](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus/master/userDefineLang/default/udl_default.png))
>    - **[Lazy Theme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus/master/userDefineLang/lazy/userDefineLang_AHK.xml)** ([Preview](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jNizM/ahk_notepad-plus-plus/master/userDefineLang/lazy/udl_lazy.png))

[image: AutoHotkey highlighting default theme]

Comment: Worked great on 2019-5-7 on win10 npp 7.6.6

Comment: The way "block comments" are defined in the linked script breaks AHK portable 2.2.0.0

Comment: Is there any way to include AHK in the Style Configurator?

Comment: could anyone elucidate for me what the differences between the default and the "lazy" theme are? Is there a different functionality/philosophy in mind?

Comment: I know jNizM and the AHK community is lucky to have him. If I had a dollar for each time one of his posts on the forums helped me solve a problem in my code, I could buy a new 4090 graphics card tonight. Great post @Stevoisiak! :D

Comment: compatible with autohotkey version 2 ?